# discord.js - Issues with audio and playing in more than one server

Tags: discord, discord.js, fs

```js
async function play(message, correct, channel, mp3) {
  const connection = await channel.join();
  await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 1000));
  let readStream = await fs.createReadStream(mp3);
  await timerEventEmitter.emit("update", correct);
  const dispatcher = await connection.play(readStream)
      .on('end', () => {
          console.log('Stream ended!');
      })
      .on('finish', () => {
          console.log('Stream finished!');
      })
      .on('error', error => {
          console.error(error);
      });
  timerEventEmitter.on('end', (time) => {
      dispatcher.destroy();
  })
}
```

This might be a big or small issue, I hope it's the latter but it's most likely the former. My bot is supposed to play audio in a voice chat and it works perfectly fine in one server.

**However, when I try playing audio at the same time in two different servers, the audio does some weird stuff.** The audio cuts out and ends in one server while playing the other audio in the other server.

Below is the code from above that I use to play the audio. I'm not really getting an error but I do need maybe an explanation or a solution if I want to add this bot to multiple servers. I'm sure there's a good explanation; hopefully it doesn't require a rework.

Also, it's not a bad connection issue either as I tried it on localhost and replit, and they both had that same issue.

```js
let readStream = await fs.createReadStream(mp3);

const dispatcher = await connection.play(readStream);
```

Comment: On your local system, what are the specs? I doubt repl.it would be able to keep up with streaming audio to multiple servers at the same time

Comment: Hi Pent, just realized the mistake I made.  I used youtube-dl to download a file called file.mp3 and replaced the old one everytime.  So basically I was removing and replacing the mp3 file everytime someone called the audio command, and losing connection.  Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Ah right, have you got it fixed now?

Comment: Yes I did!  I randomly generated a 6 digit number as the name of each mp3 (deleted it afterwords) so I don't think I will be running into this particular issue anymore